# Problem with an easy application in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to learn using Flutter, and i tried to do an easy application, but there is an error. Can you help me to fix it and tell me what's the problem? I Can't post the code, i give you an image

**Error:**

> 'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart': Failed assertion: line 285
>   pos 10: 'data != null' : A non-null String must be provided to a Text
>   widget.

[image]

Comment: this.text is null in your AppBar

Comment: how can i change his value?

Comment: add a null check like text == null ?'Empty:text

Comment: It seems when you create the instantiate the widget, you don't provide the title

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a class member with `this`.
In other languages this is pretty common (e.g. in JavaScript), but in Dart this is not needed.

Try this:

```dart
void main() => runApp(new OrangeContainer(title: 'APP TITLE'));
class OrangeContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  OrangeContainer({
    @required this.text,
  }) : assert (text != null);

  final String text;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(text),
      ),
      body: Container(
        // <-- insert your color and Boxdecoration here
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Also keep in mind, that you do not need to add the `new` keyword everytime (it became optional with Dart 2v).

As a further improvement you can add `: assert(text != null)` just after the class invocation at the beginning. This will tell you when a member is not set while developing.